# Shell Scripting: Comparing something to nothing?

Tags: shell-script

I have this script to check for internet connectivity. I use ping for it. Whenever I use `ping google.com -c 4 | grep time` it produces a non-empty response. Something like 
`64 bytes from hkg03s11-in-f4.1e100.net (173.194.127.68): icmp_req=2 ttl=52 time=90.6 ms`. But, when connectivity is down, the `time` part does not show up, therefore, when I execute the same command, it shows up as empty. How do I use `if` for it? I'm confused whether to use `" "` or `""`.

Which one do I use?

`if [ 'ping google.com -c 4 | grep time' != " " ]; then`

or

`if [ 'ping google.com -c 4 | grep time' != "" ]; then`

Notice the space between the `""`

Comment: Try echoing `$?` after running your ping. It'll be different values if it worked or not.

Comment: Use the SECOND choice:  ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[ … != " " ]` compares the left-hand side with a string containing a single space. `[ … != "" ]` compares the left-hand side with an empty string. Shell programming has oddities and pitfalls, but this particular case is straightforward.

`'ping google.com -c 4 | grep time'` is a literal 32-character string. You presumably meant to use the output of the command, i.e. a [command susbtitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution). You can use backquotes for that (instead of the forward quotes that you used), or dollar-parenthesis which is more readable and less error-prone in some complex cases. Either way, you need double quotes around the whole thing, otherwise the result of the command substitution would be [split into words and further nastiness](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

```
if [ "$(ping google.com -c 4 | grep time)" != "" ]; then …
```

All of this is a rather roundabout, brittle way of testing connectivity. Use the return status from `ping` instead. A single packet is probably enough, and you should specify a fairly small timeout in case the network is down. Pinging `google.com` tests whether both IP connectivity and DNS are working. You can ping `8.8.8.8` to test whether IPv4 connectivity is working (8.8.8.8 is a server run by Google).

```
if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null; then
  echo "The network is up"
else
  echo "The network is down"
fi
```

See also [Shell Scripting: Proper way to check for internet connectivity?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190513/shell-scripting-proper-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity/190615#190615)

Comment: I should have used a forward quote but the stack exchange markdown acts funny.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
 if ping google.com -c 4
 then 
     ... OK
 else
     ... not OK
 fi
```

like most unix command ping will give a return code that can be tested.

To answer Original question, you can't directly write empty string, you should use

```
if [ x'ping google.com -c 4 | grep time' != x ]; then
```

- if `ping google.com -c 4 | grep time` give empty string x will equal x

Comment: You _can_ "write empty string". The problem was with the OP using the wrong types of quotes. It should be (from a syntax point of view) `[ "\`ping google.com -c 4 | grep time\`" != "" ]` or better: `[ -n "$(ping google.com -c 4 | grep time)" ]`. Though of course you'd want `if ping... | grep -q time...`.

Comment: If you're testing command's return code, it's good idea to silent the command output entirely with `> /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score -1):

Between the two alternatives you have provided, later one is correct:

`if [ 'ping google.com -c 4 | grep time' != "" ]; then`

You can store `something` to a variable, say `var`, and check if it is empty using `[ -z "$var ]"`. If it is empty, its exit status `$?` would be zero.

Check:

```
$ var="something"
$ [ -z "$var" ]
$ echo $?
1

$ var=""
$ [ -z "$var" ]
$ echo $?
0
```

You can test for internet connectivity, you may use following one liner:

```
ping  -s 1 -c 1 -W 2 -q www.google.com && echo "SUCCESS" || echo "FAILURE"
```

With `-s 1`, we will send only 1 byte of data.
With `-c 1`, we will send only one ICMP packet.
With `-W 2`, we specify that, we are going to wait only for 2 seconds for a ping response.